# Laravel 5.1 Distant relationships with one-to-many and many-to-many models

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, one-to-many

I have 5 models configured. Customer, Environment, Object, ServiceRole and Service.  I've set up the appropriate eloquent relationships in each of the models.

Customers have many Environments.

```
//Customer Model    
public function environments()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\Environment');
}
```

Environments belong to one Customer.
Environments belong to many Objects.

```
//Environment Model   
public function customer()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer');
}

public function objects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Object');
}
```

Objects belong to many Environments.
Objects belong to many ServiceRoles.

```
//Object Model
public function environments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Environment');
}

public function serviceRoles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\ServiceRole');
}
```

ServiceRoles belong to many Objects.
ServiceRoles belong to one Service.

```
//ServiceRole Model
public function objects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Object');
}

public function service()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Service');
}
```

Services belong to many ServiceRoles.

```
public function serviceRoles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ServiceRole');
}
```

--SQL--
**customers**: id, name
**objects**: id, name
**environments**: id, name, customer_id
**environment_object**: id, environment_id, object_id
**service_roles**: id, name, service_id
**object_service_role**: id, object_id, service_role_id
**services**: id, name

**1) What would be the simplest method to retrieve all of the Objects that associated to the Customer (across all of the related Environments)?**

Looking to do something like: $customer->objects

**2) How can I then retrieve all the Services of the Objects associated to the Customer, as each Object has a ServiceRole that maps to a Service.**

Looking to do something like: $customer->services

Comment: Apologies, I've added the models and modified my second question slightly to reflect another model which I had missed.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It will be good to post all your relationships. But if you say you have appropriatly set up your relationships then the following should work.

```
 1. Customer::with('environments.objects')->get();
```

but if its for only a customer do

```
 Custmer::with('environments.objects')->find($id);


 2. Customer::with('environments.objects.roles')->get();
```

for only a customer do

```
 Customer::with('environments.objects.roles')->find($id);
```

Comment: This seems to retrieve nested collections, which I must loop through.  Is there a way to have only the "objects" and "services" be retrieved?  I also added my models and clarified my second question, as I wasn't too clear on the overall db design. Thanks!